# How does bootstrap determine checked state of checkbox/radiobutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently trying to debug an application that consumes bootstrap HTML and CSS and converts it to a different document format. When using the 'custom-control-input' class for styling on the checkboxes, the checkboxes are being displayed but the 'checked' attribute is lost and I end up with an unchecked bootstrap checkbox.

I'm certain the application checks to see if the attribute is set, and normal checkboxes get parsed correctly.

I know that when bootstrap is used to create checkboxes in the following way:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultUnchecked">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultUnchecked">Default unchecked</label>
```

bootstrap uses opacity to hide the checkbox and then uses the 'custom control label' to display the bootstrap checkbox.

What I cannot seem to figure out is how bootstrap then determines if the checkbox is supposed to be checked. Does it use only CSS rules for this, or is there some JavaScript/JQuery involved?

Comment: Yep, there's definitely JavaScript involved. That is how it is able to change the look and feel of a page beyond what CSS can do. A lot of the time, the underlying control (checkbox in the case) is hidden and extra HTML is added (and styled) in place of the control

Comment: There is no javascript, this is achieved using only css, `:checked` pseudo-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked how bootstrap works in this case, this is done with the help of a `:checked` pseudo-class. Link https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:checked.

Here is the relatively all code that is a bootstrap implementation.

```css
.custom-control {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    min-height: 1.5rem;
    padding-left: 1.5rem;
}

.custom-control-input {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1.25rem;
    opacity: 0;
}

.custom-control-label {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::before {
    color: #fff;
    border-color: #007bff;
    background-color: #007bff;
}
.custom-checkbox .custom-control-label::before {
    border-radius: .25rem;
}
.custom-control-label::before, .custom-file-label, .custom-select {
    transition: background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
.custom-control-label::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: .25rem;
    left: -1.5rem;
    display: block;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    pointer-events: none;
    content: "";
    background-color: #fff;
    border: #adb5bd solid 1px;
}

.custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::after {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='8' height='8' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath fill='%23fff' d='M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538-1.55L0 4.26l2.974 2.99L8 2.193z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}
.custom-control-label::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: .25rem;
    left: -1.5rem;
    display: block;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    content: "";
    background: no-repeat 50%/50% 50%;
}
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="exampleCheck1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey bhoodream, You're completely correct! I sadly didn't have time to wait so I had figured it out myself as well by this point. It seems like the converter application doesn't use the General sibling combinator '~' correctly and so it did not apply the SVG icon as background as well as the background color :) Thanks for the answer though!